# Waiting for task to finish before closing form

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task, deadlock

How can I make the FormClosing event handler (which executes on UI thread) wait for a task, that does invokes on the very same form, to complete?

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cancelUpdater.Cancel(); // CancellationTokenSource
        if (!updater.IsCompleted)
        {
            this.Hide();
            updater.Wait(); // deadlock if updater task is inside invoke
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelUpdater = new CancellationTokenSource();
        updater = new Task(() => { Updater(cancelUpdater.Token); });
        updater.Start();
    }
    void Updater(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                ...
            }));
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? The form staying open? Then simply abort the close request.

Comment: @usr If I cancel the close event, and I instruct the task to close the form when finished, then the Close() method called by a form B will return immediately and the changes that form B will make will crash the updater. The updater needs to be stopped before Close() returns so that form B can apply some changes. After the changes are made, the initial form and the updater can be reinitialized.

Comment: You lost me there... What is form B and why can't it apply changes?

Comment: @usr form B is another form opened by the main form (a settings window with a bunch of checkboxes and an apply button). These configurations affect how the main form looks and implicitly what controls are modified by the updater. If the updater is running when the changes are made, it will throw exceptions because it will try to access controls that don't exists. These configurations are stored in a "global" static class and are accessed by multiple forms.

Comment: If you cancel the form close the form will still be there. No exceptions. Nothing changes.

Comment: Could you use a class member CountdownEvent and then before your lambda expression do countdown.AddCount() and inside your lambda after Updater(...) do countdown.Signal() and then in your FormClosing just do countdown.Wait().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to deal with this is to cancel the `Close` event, and then close the form for real when the task completes. That might look something like this:

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    cancelUpdater.Cancel(); // CancellationTokenSource
    if (!updater.IsCompleted)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
        await updater;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, in your comments, you wrote:

> the Close() method called by a form B will return immediately and the changes that form B will make will crash the updater

Since you did not post any code related to "form B", it is not clear why or how it has anything to do with the current `Form1` code. It's likely that there's a good way to fix this "form B" so that it cooperates better with the `Form1` class and the object that's closing. But without seeing an actual [good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows this interaction, it's not possible to suggest how that would work.

Frankly, it is beyond being a really bad idea to block in *any* UI event handler. It is really important for the UI thread to be permitted to continue running unabated, and to do otherwise is to invite deadlock. You have of course here found one example of deadlock. But it is far from assured that even if you addressed this particular example, you could avoid all other instances of deadlock.

Blocking the UI thread is just asking for deadlock, among other problems.

That said, if you cannot resolve this issue with "form B" and really feel you must block the thread, you could make the cross-thread invoke use `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()` (which makes the invoke itself asynchronous, so that your "update thread" will be able to continue running and then terminate). Of course, should you do that, you will have to change the code to deal with the fact that by the time your invoked code is running, the form has been closed. That may or may not be a simple fix.

All that said, while I can't be sure lacking a good code example, I strongly suspect that you really should not have this updater task in the first place, and instead should be using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class. That class is specifically designed for dealing with periodic events that have to be executed in the UI thread.

**For example:**

First, drag and drop a `Timer` object onto your form in the designer. By default, the name will be `timer1`. Then set the `Interval` property to the 1000 millisecond delay you're using in your task. Also, change your `Updater()` method so it's declared as `timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` and use that as the event handler for the timer's `Tick` event.

Then, change your code so it looks something like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // All that will be left here is whatever you were executing in the
    // anonymous method you invoked. All that other stuff goes away.
    ...
}
```

Since the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class raises its `Tick` event on the UI thread, there are no thread race conditions. If you stop the timer in the `FormClosing` event, that's it. The timer's stopped. And of course, since the timer's `Tick` event is raised on the UI thread, there's no need to use `Invoke()` to execute your code.

IMHO, the above is the very best answer that can be offered given the information in the question. If you feel none of the above is useful or applies, please edit your question to provide all of the relevant details, including a good code example.

Comment: Oh, the timer is perfect. Thank you so much! Sometimes everything is out there, you just need to know where to look for.